# Why does print('%r' % 0 == 0) print False?

Tags: python

So this seems perplexing to me. I initially thought what was going on was that python was just using %r to call repr() on the first 0, and ignoring the rest of the expression, but repr(0) is actually '0', not False.

So it seems like it's treating that 0 == 0 expression as a boolean, but just... the wrong value...?

We get the correct answer if we wrap it with parentheses, but this still seems perplexing.

Comment: If `'%r' % 0` evaluates to `"0"` then `0 != "0"`

Comment: It is grouped as `('%r' % 0) == 0` not as `'%r' % (0 == 0)`, so `'0' != 0`

Comment: because `'0' == 0` is false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but repr(0) is actually '0', not False

Close, just you forgot the `== 0` part. So it's `print('0' == 0)`, which is indeed `False`.

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html writes about operator precedence, and `%` as string formatting has the same precedence as `%` as remainder, so it's higher than comparison.

> ...
> `*`, `@`, `/`, `//`, `%` ..... Multiplication, ..., remainder [6]
> ...
> in, ..., `==` ..... Comparisons, including membership tests and identity tests
> ...
> ...
> [6] The `%` operator is also used for string formatting; the same precedence applies.